# How To Solve A Sequence Question

Tags: r, basis-function

I'm taking a course on R on edx, but I have been stocked here for days. Please 
Which integer values are between the maximum and minimum heights? For example, if the minimum height is 10.2 and the maximum height is 20.8, your answer should be x <- 11:20 to capture the integers in between those values. (If either the maximum or minimum height are integers, include those values too.)

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may benefit from using the `floor()` and `ceiling()` functions in R.  Ceiling will take a number and round it up to the next highest integer (or leave it as-is if it is an integer).  For example, `ceiling(10.2)` will return 11.  Conversely, floor will round a number down to the next lowest integer, so `floor(20.8)` returns 20.

Let's say your minimum and maximum are defined in R as MIN and MAX, then `x <- ceiling(MIN):floor(MAX)` should return the sequence you're looking for.

Comment: It still doesn't accept my answer to be correct. "Write code to create a vector x that includes the integers between the minimum and maximum heights." That was the question that precedes the question above and I followed your approach to get this x <- ceiling(49): floor(83) ... My minimum and maximum values are 50 and 83 respectively

Comment: I might be misinterpreting something in your comment, but if your minimum is 50, then you should use ceiling(50), not ceiling(49) -- ceiling(49) = 49, which is less than your minimum, but ceiling(50) = 50. It may help to type ?ceiling into the R console and check out the help file (which also includes info on floor and other rounding functions). In particular, if x is a single number, then ceiling(x) returns the smallest integer that is not less than x.

Comment: Alright, will try that

Comment: It worked, thanks for time